# Is there a nice tool to plot graphs of paper citations?

Tags: soft-question, software

I would like a tool which allows me to enter some paper citation, and then will begin drawing a graph, where each paper is linked to other papers that cite the original paper or are cited by it.

It seems like this would be a handy way to identify influential papers in a field at a glance.

Does anything like this already exist?

Comment: You can query Google Scholar for data and then create a graph out of it. But that is a lot of trouble. :(

Comment: http://academic.research.microsoft.com/VisualExplorer#34212628&citation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some static ones:

- [Zotero Firefox plugin for Visual Understanding Environment](https://vue-forums.uit.tufts.edu/posts/list/521.page)
- [CiteSpace](http://cluster.cis.drexel.edu/~cchen/citespace/)
- [Thesis visualization](http://longair.net/blog/2009/10/21/thesis-visualization/)

There are dynamical ones:

- [PaperCube by Peter Bergstrom](http://papercube.peterbergstrom.com/) (it's a pity the program is working only on a demo database, the sole arXiv database would be great)
- [Web of Science - Citation map](http://images.isiknowledge.com/WOK46/help/WOS/h_citation_map.html) (nice, but for seeing not exploring + only for WOS)

(I asked the same question on WebApps SE https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10058/visualization-of-citation-data but received no answers. The above is a part of question, as I am still not satisfied.)

Comment: The link of Web of Science - Citation map  is broken.

Comment: Regarding "Citation Map", as mentioned in @Gigacyan's answer [below](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/5595/35512), it seems that a university subscription is required to use this service.

Comment: This also seems like a valid candidate: https://github.com/karpathy/researchlei

Comment: Today I used https://citationgecko.azurewebsites.net/ which is not exactly a graph but I found it to be a useful visualization tool.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator this doesn't generate the citations reliably, unfortunately. Cool tool however.

Answer (score 1):

Centuries ago, there was a Touchgraph demo for Google Scholar. It was the closest thing.

Answer (score 0):

[ISI Web of Knowledge](http://isiknowledge.com) has such tool called "Citation map" but you would probably need a subscription to use this service (most universities have it, I suppose). It is Java-based and sometimes works quite slow.